# Unity - Help needed with Object Positioning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

Need some help here with unity object positioning, I've been trying to play around for almost two days and got no result.

So if you look at the image below there are 2 objects.

[image]

One is Plate (red colour)

One is Cube (blue colour)

I created the entire objects below from the script.
When the Plate (Red colour object) was generated the scale is (4 x 0.4 x 4).

And as for the cube, please look at this image, so there are 5 possible types of cube and each has its own vector size
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is that every Cube (blue colour) has it own pre-defined vector size, and when the script ran, I want to position the cube accordingly in a tidy manner on top of the Plate.

If you look at the first image, everything is messy right now the cube is outside the plate, etc.
Anyone know whats the best way to achieve what I wanted?

The image below is what I want to achieve, everything is tidy and on top of the plates.

[image]

Thanks and much appreciated!

Edit: the number of cubes is not fixed basically we populate the cubes from reading a TXT file and it tells the system the number of cubes per plate and what are the sizes of the cubes, we just need to position it correctly. For example, when reading the TXT file, it can tell the system that the first plate will be having 4 cubes and X amount of size. (so we have 5 different types of size and based on the size then we need to fit it accordingly on a plate)

Comment: Why not just spawn an empty object with 5 cubes as children?

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshot. Also refer to [mcve].

Comment: To help you we need more information on your scenario. (Like how many cubes do you want per plate, is this number fixed, do you know the amount of cubes and their sizes beforehand, is it possible to switch cubes between plates for better fitting...)

Comment: @Thomas Hi
Thanks for your reply! the number of cubes is not fixed basically we populate the cubes from reading a TXT file and it tells the system the number of cubes per plate and what are the sizes of the cubes, we just need to position it correctly. 

For example, when reading the TXT file, it can tell the system that the first plate will be having 4 cubes and X amount of size. (so we have 5 different types of size and based on the size then we need to fit it accordingly on a plate)

Comment: @jacobgalam Could you kindly explain it further?
Thank you.

Comment: @Sarah Is it save to assume that there only appear constellations in which the cubes fit onto the plate? Is there a preferable alignment for a certain cube set (n of size x + m of size y...)? Should the same cube set always result in the same alignment or should it vary?

Comment: @Thomas Hello! Thank you so much for your response, there is a pattern, the largest cube appear at the back while the smaller cube appears in front and if there is only one cube in the plate it will be positioned in the middle.

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to calculate the position of the cubes (blue) according to the boundaries of the plate.
Check here : [Bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html)

Comment: Could you kindly explain it further? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only position them in x-z-plane you can quantify your cubes' sizes (as multiples of 0.8), leaving out the y-dimension.
Then you have a plate of 5 by 5 slots and you can place the available cubes iteratively.

This is a test script first filling the rows of your plate (aka horizontally) and if necessary fitting the remaining cubes column first (aka vertically).
You may simplify this, but I think adapting it to your needs is straightforward.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class PositioningTest : MonoBehaviour {
    private const char FREE = 'x';

    private readonly Vector3Int _quantizedPlateSize = new Vector3Int(5, 1, 5);

    private readonly Vector3Int[] _quantizedCubeSize = new[]{
        new Vector3Int(1, 1, 1),
        new Vector3Int(1, 1, 1),
        new Vector3Int(2, 1, 1),
        new Vector3Int(2, 2, 2),
        new Vector3Int(4, 2, 2),
    };

    private Transform _plate;

    [SerializeField]
    private int[] _availableCubes;

    private void OnGUI() {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 100), "Run")) {
            if (_availableCubes == null || _availableCubes.Length == 0)
                return;
            List<Vector3Int> cubes = new List<Vector3Int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < _availableCubes.Length; i++) {
                int sizeIndex = _availableCubes[i];
                if (sizeIndex < 0 || sizeIndex >= _quantizedCubeSize.Length) {
                    Debug.LogError("invalid size index " + sizeIndex);
                    return;
                }
                cubes.Add(_quantizedCubeSize[sizeIndex]);
            }
            PlaceCubesOnPlate(cubes, _quantizedPlateSize.x, _quantizedPlateSize.z);
        }
    }

    private void PlaceCubesOnPlate(List<Vector3Int> allCubes, int plateRows, int plateColumns) {
        if (allCubes == null || allCubes.Count == 0) {
            Debug.LogError("no cubes to position");
            return;
        }

        // reset the plate
        ResetPlate();
        char[,] plate = CreateEmptyPlate(plateRows, plateColumns);

        // sort them so we fit the biggest cubes first
        SortCubesDescending(ref allCubes);

        // index of the cube to be fit in next
        int currentCubeIndex = 0;

        // fit the cubes row first
        for (int z = 0; z < plate.GetLength(0); z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < plate.GetLength(1); x++) {
                if (plate[z, x] != FREE)
                    continue;
                Vector3Int cube = allCubes[currentCubeIndex];
                if (TryPositionCubeRowFirst(ref plate, cube, z, x, GetChar(currentCubeIndex))) {
                    currentCubeIndex++;
                    if (currentCubeIndex == allCubes.Count) {
                        PrintPlate(plate);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // fit remaining cubes column first
        for (int x = 0; x < plate.GetLength(1); x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < plate.GetLength(0); z++) {
                if (plate[z, x] != FREE)
                    continue;
                Vector3Int cube = allCubes[currentCubeIndex];
                if (TryPositionCubeColumnFirst(ref plate, cube, z, x, GetChar(currentCubeIndex))) {
                    currentCubeIndex++;
                    if (currentCubeIndex == allCubes.Count) {
                        PrintPlate(plate);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Debug.LogError("could not fit all cubes");
    }

    private char[,] CreateEmptyPlate(int rows, int columns) {
        char[,] plate = new char[columns, rows];
        for (int z = 0; z < plate.GetLength(0); z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < plate.GetLength(1); x++) {
                plate[z, x] = FREE;
            }
        }
        return plate;
    }

    private void SortCubesDescending(ref List<Vector3Int> cubes) {
        cubes.Sort((c1, c2) => {
            int indexC1 = Array.IndexOf(_quantizedCubeSize, c1);
            int indexC2 = Array.IndexOf(_quantizedCubeSize, c2);
            return indexC2.CompareTo(indexC1);
        });
    }

    private void PrintPlate(char[,] plate) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("plate:\n");
        for (int z = 0; z < plate.GetLength(0); z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < plate.GetLength(1); x++) {
                sb.Append(plate[z, x]);
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
            sb.Append("\n");
        }
        Debug.Log(sb.ToString());
    }

    private char GetChar(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index <= 15)
            return index.ToString("X")[0];
        return (char) (Math.Abs(index) - 16 + 97);
    }

    private bool TryPositionCubeRowFirst(ref char[,] plate, Vector3Int cubeSize, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, char representingChar) {
        for (int z = 0; z < cubeSize.z; z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < cubeSize.x; x++) {
                if (columnIndex + z >= plate.GetLength(0)
                    || rowIndex + x >= plate.GetLength(1)
                    || plate[columnIndex + z, rowIndex + x] != FREE)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < cubeSize.z; z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < cubeSize.x; x++) {
                plate[columnIndex + z, rowIndex + x] = representingChar;
            }
        }

        Transform newCube = CreateCube(representingChar.ToString(), _plate, new Vector3(rowIndex, 0, columnIndex));
        newCube.localScale = cubeSize;
        return true;
    }

    private bool TryPositionCubeColumnFirst(ref char[,] plate, Vector3Int cubeSize, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, char representingChar) {
        for (int z = 0; z < cubeSize.z; z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < cubeSize.x; x++) {
                if (columnIndex + x >= plate.GetLength(0)
                    || rowIndex + z >= plate.GetLength(1)
                    || plate[columnIndex + x, rowIndex + z] != FREE)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < cubeSize.z; z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < cubeSize.x; x++) {
                plate[columnIndex + x, rowIndex + z] = representingChar;
            }
        }

    
        Transform newCube = CreateCube(representingChar.ToString(), _plate, new Vector3(rowIndex, 0, columnIndex));
        newCube.localScale = new Vector3(cubeSize.z, cubeSize.y, cubeSize.x);
        return true;
    }

    private void ResetPlate() {
        if (_plate != null) {
            Destroy(_plate.gameObject);
        }
        _plate = new GameObject("plate").transform;
    }

    private Transform CreateCube(string name, Transform parent, Vector3 localPosition) {
        Transform pivot = new GameObject(name).transform;
        Transform cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube).transform;
        cube.SetParent(pivot);
        cube.localPosition = new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F);
        cube.localScale = new Vector3(0.9F, 0.9F, 0.9F);
        pivot.SetParent(parent);
        pivot.localPosition = localPosition;
        return pivot;
    }
}
```

Note: The resulting debug output is upside down (compared to the unity scene), since both are just representations for understanding the algorithm.

If you only have one cube and want that one positioned in the center of the plate you might just add a check in the positioning method allowing an early return for one cube (like it already has for 0 cubes).

Comment: Thanks Thomas!
Much appreciate your help, I am now trying to understand the codes above, and will get back to you if I have any question. Have a good day!

Comment: Hello @Thomas, thanks again for your assistance. Do you know how to create a Plate directly under the cube? because you have been using this char 2 dimensions. 
What I want to achieve is that for every cube, there will be a plate directly under and the plate has to be tidy and in sync with another plate (basically whole plate like the picture)

Comment: Well the algorithm is just calculating the position of objects of a given size in an area of given size. Actual object creation, coloring, animation... is all completely independent. (The cubes in my example are actually just for visualization. They do not have your desired size and only serve as preview for the alignment result.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you available for a chat via chat.stackoverflow? I am real rookie and having some difficulty understanding it. Let me know if you are available.

Comment: If you are not available, is it possible for you to convert the above codes into using Vector 3 instead of VectorInt ? because I have to use a float value and not Int. Thanks!